# Update Subview in a Xib while animating bounds of superview

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I am working on animating in a modal-like window, which has been built in a Xib using auto-layout constraints. I am attempting to make it appear to grow from a UITableViewCell on tap. I've noticed that only the superview will animate it's bounds (width and height) using CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size"), while none of it's subviews change at all.

I do not want to use CATransform3D as that ends up distorting images and text in the subview.I've also tried layoutIfNeeded() before and after the animation, but it doesn't seem to make a difference on animating the subviews.I also tried snapshotting, but it would not work because the view is not rendered on the screen until the animation begins.

Any thoughts on making this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is subviews constrained to their superview (autolayout) ?
If yes maybe you should try to call self.layoutIfNeeded() in your animation

Comment: Yes, they are constrained to the superview - the xib is built using autolayout. I have tried using layoutIfNeeded() with no luck..

Comment: Can you provide more details about the view stack ? When you say superview you mean the contentView of the cell or the root view of the tableView or other thing ?

Comment: i am creating a custom animation transition - so on-click of a cell in a table view launches a xib controller..Superview = rootview of xib file